# How do I capture the argument to a function and apply them as is in another context/environment

Tags: r, tidyeval

I am pretty sure my language is imprecise, but I don't know the correct terms yet. This is what I wanted to achieve:

I have a function `abc2`. I want to obtain the arguments to them (without evaluating or changing the argument) provided by the user, to use in another function. E.g.

```r
abc2 <- function(...) {
 # what do I have to do here?
}

adf = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
bdf = data.frame(a = 11:13, b = 11:33)
```

such that calling `abc2(a)` is the same as calling

```r
dplyr::select(adf, a)
dplyr::select(bdf, a)
```

and that calling `abc2("a")` is the same as calling

```r
dplyr::select(adf, "a")
dplyr::select(bdf, "a")
```

Basically, I want to transplant the `...` from abc2 and apply them without any change from how the user has input it and apply elsewhere.

Base R and tidyeval explanation welcome! I am trying to read up on `quo` and `enquo` but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) base R** Pass `...` on.  Either `"a"` or just `a` can be used.  The passing mechanism here uses only base R.  The dplyr is only so that we can use `select`.

```
library(dplyr)

adf = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
bdf = data.frame(a = 11:13, b = 21:23)

abc2 <- function(...) {
  print(select(adf, ...))
  print(select(bdf, ...))
}

# or: abc2(a)
abc2("a")
```

giving:

```
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
   a
1 11
2 12
3 13
```

**2) rlang** This also works but this time we use rlang's enquos and !!! with tidyeval all of which is pulled in by dplyr.

```
abc2a <- function(...) {
  dots <- enquos(...)
  print(select(adf, !!!dots))
  print(select(bdf, !!!dots))
}
abc2(a)
```